# Lost debug.keystore, can I update the Android app or retrieve the app data?

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

We have an internally deployed company app that has been signed with a developer's debug.keystore. The debug.keystore has been lost. Is there any possible way to:

1. Update a copy of the app using a new debug key.
2. Failing 1, is there any way an app with a new debug key could access the data of the already installed app (e.g. extract the data somehow, install the old and new apps side-by-side, adb uninstall -k)? The app does not have the debuggable flag set in its manifest.

I know the above is unlikely but I wanted to confirm before considering options as most stories about this concern Android market apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no way around this.